# What ID should I put in the WebApplicationInfo of an Office Add-in's manifest file?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/webapplicationinfo), it states:

> `Id`: The Application Id of the add-in's associated service as registered in the Azure Active Directory v 2.0 endpoint.

I still don't understand where to get this ID from? Do I need to register an app at `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com` and add this ID or is it something else?

I am trying to retrieve Office bootstrap token, but it's not working probably due to this ID parameter. Otherwise, my manifest is approved

```
Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function (result) {

getAccessTokenAsync fails with error 13004
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for application Id you have to register your application on [azure v2.0 application portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com). Which will create a unique application Id

As you are using  [Azure Active Directory v 2.0 endpoint portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com). To register your application on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com you do have to login there and have to register new app.

Once your application registration succeeded you will get your application id below.

For application registration see the step below:

**Step 1**

Enter a meaningful application name and click create application.

[image]

**Step 2**

Once you created your application successfully You will see your application Id right

below the application name. see the screen shot below.

[image]

***You can also get following information:***

***Password***

***Application secret key***

***Preferred application platform***

***Application permission***

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have two questions: 1. Should I register this app with the ADMINISTRATOR account for the tenant and 2. Reading this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2 I am confused by step #10. What are these three IDs (Microsoft Office) (Office Online)? Do I need to add them anywhere? These three in particular?

Comment: @nmrlqa4 Yes you need to have admin consent as the document said in No 2 clause and also need to enter that three add -in  one after another.

Comment: Ok, and the article says that for each of these three I should add "api://$FQDN-WITHOUT-PROTOCOL$/$App ID GUID$/access_as_user". Is this "/access_as_user" what needs to be added exactly or I can use other scopes for example "/profile"? (BTW the addin website is hosted on Azure)

Comment: @nmrlqa4 No you cannot you have to follow the clause No 11 accordingly like : Open the Scope drop-down beside each Application ID and check the box for : api://$FQDN-WITHOUT-PROTOCOL$/$App ID GUID$/access_as_user

Comment: @nmrlqa4 if the answer worked You could marked it for helping others. Thanks